# Android Fragments and findFragmentByTag()

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a parent FragmentActivity with three child Tab Fragments. When a "Submit" button is pressed on the FragmentActivity, I want to sum the values of all the EditText fields in the different Tab Fragments. I think I have the right idea, using getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(), however I'm finding that it is only returning values for the current active Fragment. I was under the assumption that I could access the inactive (or not visible) Tab Fragment's as well:

```
int sum1 = getSupplyQuantities(Constants.TAB_TAG1);
int sum2 = getSupplyQuantities(Constants.TAB_TAG2);
int sum3 = getSupplyQuantities(Constants.TAB_TAG3);
int sum4 = getSupplyQuantities(Constants.TAB_TAG4);

private int getSupplyQuantities(String string) {
    Activity tab = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(string)
            .getActivity();

    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) tab
            .findViewById(R.id.get_supplies_layout);

            int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View view = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);

        QuantityTextView quantity = (QuantityTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.get_supplies_list_quantity);

        sum += Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());

    }

    return sum;

}
```

In the above scenario, sum1, sum2, sum3, and sum4 will all be the same. They will be the sum for the active Tab Fragment.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barak mentioned above, you need to get a hold of the fragment(s) that contain the view(s). Keep in mind that if you use some kind of a view pager, depending on how it's configured, only the currently visible page/fragment is instantiated.

Solutions:

1. You can keep track of the fragments or containing views in a cache if you don't have many fragments.
2. Use the ViewHolder pattern to "cache" the relevant data that you need to access.

Comment: Hi tamsler, thanks for the advice. I kept track of the containing views in a cache, and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the view for the fragment rather than the activity.

By getting the activity youare asking for the active fragment.

Comment: Hi Barak, I tried using View tab = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(string).getView(); to get the Fragment View, but I'm running into the same issue. The view will be null for every Fragment except the active one. Am I getting the view wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm at the limit of my knowledge... I've never done tabs with fragments, nor used tags for fragments. I would think that the overall fragment views must still be around (why re-create them each time you switch between them?), but I have no clue how you would access them.

Answer (score 0):

in android samples there are an example about how to use tabs with fragments.
just take look at "...\android-sdk\samples\android-15\" and find there "ApiDemos" example project (you need "FragmentTabs.java" file).

about edittexts:  you can add getTextFromEdittext() method to your fragment class, and then just call it from FragmentActivity when you need.